# SSH don't work in the QProcess,but it works in the console

Tags: c++, qt, ssh, qprocess

I have this code:

```
QProcess* proc = new QProcess();  
proc->start("cmd.exe");
proc->write("ssh\n");
proc->closeWriteChannel();
proc->waitForFinished();
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("IBM 866");
ui->textEditNormal->setText(codec->toUnicode(proc->readAllStandardOutput()));
ui->textEditError->setText(codec->toUnicode(proc->readAllStandardError()));
```

Writes in a  `StandartError`:

```
'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

If I repeat everything in a `cmd.exe`, then everything is fine
How to fix it?

Comment: Maybe PATH is not what you expect it to be? Try with the absolute path to ssh.exe

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should wait for the process being started before writing to it. The following example does something similar. I don't have ssh installed so I issued `dir` on my Windows machine. Just try it.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QProcess>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    auto process = new QProcess;
    auto view = new QTextBrowser;
    process->setWorkingDirectory("C:/Temp");
    QObject::connect(process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [process,view]() {
        auto output=process->readAllStandardOutput();
        view->append(output);
    });
    QObject::connect(process, &QProcess::readyReadStandardError, [process,view]() {
        auto output=process->readAllStandardError();
        view->append(output);
    });
    process->start("cmd.exe");
    process->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);

    process->waitForStarted();
    process->write("dir\n");
    qDebug() << process->error();
    view->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```